# ISAPI Rewrite Rule - Want to Eliminate Some Characters

Tags: url-rewriting, isapi, isapi-rewrite, isapi-redirect

I am using isapi rewrite and i am having a url
www.example.com/<%25=sSiteURL%25>/abc/abc/abc/abc/abc/1883.htm

I want to remove this string
<%25=sSiteURL%25>

I want the url to be like this
www.example.com/abc/abc/abc/abc/abc/1883.htm

Can anyone please help me in this

Answer (score 0):

Try the following rules (providing you have ISAPI_Rewrite 3):

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^<.*>(.*)$ $1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi Tony Many Thanks for your answer, but it didn't work. I have isapi_rewrite 3, but it does not work.. i just want to remove <%25=sSiteURL%25>